# How does a robust http server handle requests?

Tags: architecture, c, performance, web-services, http

I have written many http(s) servers in Node.js and just take for granted that I can receive many requests and all IO operations are async. However, now I would like to try and implement an HTTP server in C, like [this one](https://github.com/wasmerio/c-http-server/blob/master/main.c#L91-L100), but I'm wondering what it would look like to be robust.

Specifically, what I mean is, I don't want to see a full fledged HTTP framework in C because they are quite large and complicated. But I just would like to understand how to maximize the number of requests and handle the requests efficiently on one server.

Is it just as simple as a `while (1)` loop to look for incoming socket connections and then parse the HTTP request and server a response in one fell swoop? (Assuming we don't have any async resources we are fetching in this simplified example)?

Or are there more tricks you need to do somewhere within this, such as creating a queue of incoming requests before processing them, then partially process them in a round robin sort of fashion until they are individually done. Or something along those lines. Wondering if one could outline what needs to be done to maximize performance/throughput.

Comment: I want to learn how to implement it at the lowest level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maximizing throughput *requires* the use of async techniques, which C is very bad at. The issue with a while-loop that accepts and handles new connections is that we can only process one request at a time, and that processing this request is typically IO-bound: speed is dependent on the connection to the client, and even on the client itself. If we don't receive the next TCP packet, the entire loop is blocked until the connection times out!

So what servers in C typically do is fork() immediately after accepting a request, or passing the accepted file handle to a pre-forked pool of workers (see: Apache), or using threads instead of processes. Now, the number of requests that can be in flight is limited by the number of worker threads/processes. There is considerable overhead with this approach, limiting how far it can scale. There is context-switching overhead from juggling all those processes, and there is a memory overhead of at least a few KB for each worker. Most of the workers will always be idle, because they are waiting for some IO operation (read or write) to complete.

A scalable server will therefore have to use event-driven, non-blocking techniques. To a small degree, this can be managed with select() or poll() in POSIX. More practical are non-portable APIs like epoll() in Linux or kqueue() in FreeBSD (which are all predated by IOCP in Windows NT). You wouldn't use those directly, but use an event loop library like libuv or libevent.

[Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/events.html) uses precisely such event driven IO facilities to efficiently multiplex connections. Node.JS combines the V8 JavaScript engine with libuv and is probably one of the most accessible platforms to write async servers. However, we are now also seeing systems programming languages getting good abstractions for async operations. Async/await syntax was pioneered in .NET languages, and is also available in Rust and C++20. This allows for much less overhead per in-flight request, and makes it comparatively easy to integrate an event loop, without having to manually encode a state machine.

Comment: How does the nonblocking technique work / solve the problem? I understand how it frees up processing, but how does it actually work, is it writing to disk and then queuing up something or something like that? Taking a look at [how libuv works](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html) I guess :)

Comment: If you want to know how async programming works, you could look into JavaScript and Node.js. They provide a good high-level overview. Basically, you tell the OS to perform some I/O operation, and supply a callback function, which the OS then calls when the I/O is ready.

Comment: "Delegating potentially-blocking operations to a thread pool isn't good for just silly demos and CPU-intensive computations; libuv itself makes heavy use of this capability in its file-system APIs. This way, libuv accomplishes the superpower of exposing the file-system with an asynchronous API, in a portable way." https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/concurrent-servers-part-4-libuv/

Comment: https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/4ed2a78f0eb1c9d2a0c98ea4a88c6824e5958dc6/src/threadpool.c#L142

Comment: @Lance The core concept is that the OS provides some way to tell us when a file handle (e.g. a socket connection) is ready so that a read() or write() on it will succeed without unnecessary blocking (the kernel has internal buffers for each file handle, so we want the buffer to already contain data if we read from it). But that isn't quite async I/O, which just doesn't exist on Linux. That's why libuv uses epoll() or whatever to find out which IO tasks can be performed now, but actually perform slow operations like writes in a separate thread.

Comment: This answer states that C is bad at async techniques so it, therefore, must pass it off to other processes or threads but those processes and threads are most likely written in C so that logic does not apply. Those are operating system issues to some extent. The fastest servers I use, nginx and h2o, are written in C.

Comment: @Rob C is bad at async stuff, just like C is bad at object-oriented stuff. It's not impossible to encode those in a C program, just very tedious. This work has been done for nginx and h2o, but someone wanting to write a new server would be better served by writing it in Rust, Go, or C#.

Comment: What one may call tedious, I call programming. I've done both server and OOP using C and would not switch to those other languages just to avoid C. I would *never* do such things in anything else but assembly.